# IP change to Domain Name in Ubuntu

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, magento

I am currently setting up Magento 2.2 for the company I am working with. I set up most of the things and installed the Magento package on the IP Host. I can access it and it kind of works fine until I go to the admin console. I found out this is happening because there is no SSL assigned to the domain name. However, as I am using an IP I cannot do it. How would I go about assigning a domain name through Ubuntu and DNS? I've pointed some of the A records to the host IP, is there anything else I need to do for this to work?

Best,
M

Comment: Did Tom's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from setting an A record in DNS — or adding an entry in your */etc/hosts* file — you must of course also request a certificate. You could get a Let's Encrypt certificate if you are using a public DNS name (e.g. www.example.com) or you can make a self-signed certificate when you are using a "private" DNS name (e.g. www.example.lan).

A self-signed certificate will still issue a warning though you can then ignore it or, better yet, set up your own internal root CA and use that to sign the certificate and install the public key of the root CA on the computers in your company.